# How do I build a multiplexer for this boolean function?

Tags: multiplexer, boolean-algebra

I have a boolean function:

$$F = \bar A·\bar B·\bar C + A·\bar C·\bar D + B·C·\bar D + \bar B·C·D$$

Where the dot means `and` and the bar means complement.

I plot the karnaugh map and got 9 min terms. How do I interpret these terms for the multiplexer? What do they actually do and what does my multiplexer need to achieve?

I don't quite get what a multiplexer is actually (intuitively). In the simplest form, what is a multiplexer? I understand it as some special switch that can select the inputs.

My goal is to build a 16:1, and then 8:1 multiplexers separately with a criteria of using one or more `NOT` gates. How should I do this?

Comment: "*what is a muiltiplexor? I understand it as some special switch that can select the inputs.*", it looks like you know what a multiplex**e**r is. - perhaps the next step would be to make a boolean expression for a multiplexer and see how you can split up your boolean function into several of your multiplexer expressions.

Comment: Start by editing your post to describe what you expect a multiplexer to do. In some detail, please.

Comment: Convert it to a 4 input NAND with four 3 input NORs or do a logic reduction homework calculation. Or use a 3bit binary decoder and gate the outputs

Answer (score 0):

An N:1 multiplexer (where N is a power of 2) will have N data inputs, 1 output, and n address inputs, where $$N = 2^n $$ Each of the N addresses specified by n will connect the N input to the output. For a 16:1 multiplexer, you can think of it a 16 5-input AND gates which feed a 16-input OR gate. The 4 address inputs each have an internal inverter so that the proper levels are fed to the appropriate AND gate.

If you want to do logic functions via a multiplexer, you simply find the inputs which produce a 1, translate those combinations to the addresses of the multiplexer (A'B'C'D' = 0, AB'C'D' = 1, A'BC'D' = 2, etc) and tie the appropriate inputs high, then tie all the other inputs low.

This is very straightforward, but it should be apparent that all of the inputs tied low will never be active, so the approach wastes a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

An N:1 multiplexer (where N is a power of 2) will have N data inputs, 1 output, and n address inputs, where $$N = 2^n $$ Each of the N addresses specified by n will connect the N input to the output. For a 16:1 multiplexer, you can think of it a 16 5-input AND gates which feed a 16-input OR gate. The 4 address inputs each have an internal inverter so that the proper levels are fed to the appropriate AND gate.

The simplest multiplexer is a 2:1, and it can be done like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsTld2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When SELECT is low, the A input is seen at the output, and when SELECT is high, the B input is selected.

If you want to do logic functions via a multiplexer, you simply find the inputs which produce a 1, translate those combinations to the addresses of the multiplexer (A'B'C'D' = 0, AB'C'D' = 1, A'BC'D' = 2, etc) and tie the appropriate inputs high, then tie all the other inputs low.

This is very straightforward, but it should be apparent that all of the inputs tied low will never be active, so the approach wastes a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a **multiplexer**, or **mux**, is a selector. The mux has many inputs, some selection variables and an output. Depending on the value of the selection variables, the mux will **select** one of its inputs, and copy its value on the output. You could also think of a mux as a switch:
[image: Image from wikipedia]

The mux of the image corresponds to a 2:1 multiplexer (2 inputs 1 output). Only one selection variable is required to unequivocally select either input 0 or input 1. When \$\text{sel}\$ equals \$0\$, \$\text{out}\$ will be equal to \$\text{I}_\text{0}\$. Similarly, When \$\text{sel}\$ equals \$1\$, \$\text{out}\$ will be equal to \$\text{I}_\text{1}\$.

We can have muxes with more inputs (but ALWAYS one output). For example, consider a 4:1 mux:

[image: Image from wikipedia 2]

Where \$\text{S}_\text{0}\$ and \$\text{S}_\text{1}\$ are the selection variables (two of them are required to generate four different combinations and be able to select one of the four inputs). So if \$\text{S}_\text{0}\$ and \$\text{S}_\text{1}\$ form the binary number \$0\$, input \$0\$ (\$\text{A}\$) will be selected; if \$\text{S}_\text{0}\$ and \$\text{S}_\text{1}\$ form the binary number \$1\$, input \$1\$ (\$\text{B}\$) will be selected and so on.

As stated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer#Multiplexers_as_PLDs), a mux can be used to implement any boolean function. Consider for example the output of the 4:1 mux, which can be expressed as:
$$
\text{Z} = \text{A} \overline{\text{S}_\text{0}} \overline{\text{S}_\text{1}} + \text{B} \text{S}_\text{0} \overline{\text{S}_\text{1}} + \text{C} \overline{\text{S}_\text{0}} \text{S}_\text{1} + \text{D} \text{S}_\text{0} \text{S}_\text{1}
$$

Notice how \$\text{Z}\$ is the sum of all the [minterms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterm) of \$\text{S}_\text{0}\$ and \$\text{S}_\text{1}\$, each of them multiplied by an input. The four inputs can be thought as the truth table of the two variables \$\text{S}_\text{0}\$ and \$\text{S}_\text{1}\$, and we can assign them zeros or ones in order to eliminate undesired minterms and leave only the minterms of the Boolean function we want. For example, if we make \$\text{A} = \text{B} = \text{C} = 0\$ and \$\text{D} = 1\$, then:
$$
\text{Z} = \text{S}_\text{0} \text{S}_\text{1}
$$

Effectively implementing an AND gate. If we want an XOR gate, we can implement it by making \$\text{A} = \text{D} = 0\$ and \$\text{B} = \text{C} = 1\$.

You can extrapolate these examples to a 16:1 mux to solve your first exercise. as for the second one, the process is more complicated, but the key is that you have to put one of the inputs of your function (and maybe its negation, too) in the appropriate inputs of the 8:1 mux. The three other function inputs act as the mux selectors as usual. Notice that for the second exercise there are various correct answers. As a hint, you can find [here](http://vlsiuniverse.blogspot.com.co/2016/05/xor-gate-using-mux.html) the implementation of an XOR gate using a 2:1 mux:
[image: image3]